# When does the signedness of an integer really matter?

Tags: c, signedness

Due to the way conversions and operations are defined in C, it seems to rarely matter whether you use a signed or an unsigned variable:

```
uint8_t u; int8_t i;

u = -3;    i = -3;
u *= 2;    i *= 2;
u += 15;   i += 15;
u >>= 2;   i >>= 2;

printf("%u",u); // -> 2
printf("%u",i); // -> 2
```

So, is there a set of rules to tell under which conditions the signedness of a variable really makes a difference?

Comment: Well, it would depend on whether or not you want your integer variable to take on negative values...

Comment: `printf("%u", i)` is wrong (undefined behaviour even, IIRC).

Comment: This is quite old & valuable article written by Scott Meyers long ago: http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/sep95.pdf

Comment: @delnan: Not true. It is specifically *not* undefined when `i` is 2 by the standard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It matters in these contexts:

- division and modulo: `-2/2 = 1`, `-2u/2 = UINT_MAX/2-1`, `-3%4 = -3`, `-3u%4 = 1`
- shifts. For negative signed values, the result of `>>` and `<<` are implementation defined or undefined, resp. For unsigned values, they are always defined.
- relationals `-2 < 0`, `-2u > 0`
- overflows. `x+1 > x` may be assumed by the compiler to be always true *iff* `x` has signed type.

Comment: That's really weird with the overflow assumption, but I verified it. It seems to me like it should be untrue when x+1 overflows, but the compiler indeed ignores that.

Comment: @NicholasFlynt: That's the beauty of undefined behaviour. Overflowing signed integer invokes undefined behaviour, where the compiler may do whatever it wants. So it asserts `x+1>x` because it can, although actual computation would have shown otherwise. At the same time, it holds for non-overflowing computation, so the compiler can assert `x+1>x` all the time, which leads to simplification of the program.

Comment: If this answer is correct, it looks like a comprehensive list. So I accepted this one and upvoted the other good answers.

Comment: @AndreKR: Almost comprehensive, I added casts to the list.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Signedness will affect the result of Greater Than and Less Than operators in C. Consider the following code:

```
unsigned int a = -5;
unsigned int b = 7;

if (a < b)
    printf("Less");
else
    printf("More");
```

In this example, "More" is incorrectly output, because the -5 is converted to a very high positive number by the compiler.

This will also affect your arithmetic with different sized variables. Again, consider this example:

```
unsigned char a = -5;
signed short b = 12;

printf("%d", a+b);
```

The returned result is **263,** not the expected 7. This is because -5 is actually treated as 251 by the compiler. Overflow makes your operations work correctly for same-sized variables, but when expanding, the compiler does not expand the sign bit for unsigned variables, so it treats them as their original positive representation in the larger sized space. Study how [two's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works and you'll see where this result comes from.

Comment: Specifically, this will affect what opcodes are used to compare the variable. The internal representation for integers does not change-- what changes is how the compiler interprets the result of the comparison.

Comment: You are right, with the result, but I would call that "incorrect". Storing a negative value in an `unsigned` should tell you that there must be something not completely trivial going on :)

Answer (score 6):

It affects the range of values that you can store in the variable.

Comment: No, it does not. I can store 129 in an int8_t without any problem as long as I interpret it as unsigned when using it.

Comment: @AndreKR: And by reinterpreting it, you're *at least* confusing the heck out of everyone. It may even be implementation-defined or undefined behaviour (though I wouldn't bet on this before consulting a language lawyer). C's type system is weak enough already, no need to make the type mean even less.

Comment: @AndreKR: That would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AndreKR, no you can't store `129` in an `int8_t`, you can store `-127` and *pretend* it being `129`. How would you do `128`?

Answer (score 3):

It is relevant mainly in comparison.

```
printf("%d", (u-3) < 0); // -> 0
printf("%d", (i-3) < 0); // -> 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Overflow on unsigned integers just wraps around. On signed values this is undefined behavior, everything can happen.

Comment: While I find it theoretically possible that *anything* might happen, I have trouble believing in the possibility that *everything* might happen. That would be one badass compiler...

Comment: anything can happen includes the possibility that even everything can happen, no ?)

Comment: @JensGustedt: Does *everything happens* include *both* the Earth colliding with the Moon and the Earth losing the Moon in the deep space?

Comment: sure, from the false follows the absurd.

Comment: If _anything_ can happen, then surely _everything_ is covered by _anything_.

Comment: @Arkku - But I'm pretty sure *everything* happening is precluded by one of the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: @T.E.D. Not sure that the laws of thermodynamics survive the collapse of the universe, though.

Answer (score 2):

The signedness of 2's complement numbers is simply just a matter of how you are interpreting the number. Imagine the 3 bit numbers:

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

If you think of `000` as zero and the numbers as they are natural to humans, you would interpret them like this:

```
000: 0
001: 1
010: 2
011: 3
100: 4
101: 5
110: 6
111: 7
```

This is called "unsigned integer". You see everything as a number bigger than/equal to zero.

Now, what if you want to have some numbers as negative? Well, 2's complement comes to rescue. 2's complement is known to most people as just a formula, but in truth it's just congruency modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits in your number.

Let me give you a few examples of congruency:

```
2 = 5 = 8 = -1 = -4 module 3
-2 = 6 = 14 module 8
```

Now, just for convenience, let's say you decide to have the left most bit of a number as its sign. So you want to have:

```
000: 0
001: positive
010: positive
011: positive
100: negative
101: negative
110: negative
111: negative
```

Viewing your numbers congruent modulo 2^3 (= 8), you know that:

```
4 = -4
5 = -3
6 = -2
7 = -1
```

Therefore, you view your numbers as:

```
000: 0
001: 1
010: 2
011: 3
100: -4
101: -3
110: -2
111: -1
```

As you can see, the actual bits for -3 and 5 (for example) are the same (if the number has 3 bits). Therefore, writing `x = -3` or `x = 5` gives you the same result.

Interpreting numbers congruent modulo 2^n has other benefits. If you sum 2 numbers, one negative and one positive, it could happen on paper that you have a carry that would be thrown away, yet the result is still correct. Why? That carry was a 2^n which is congruent to 0 modulo 2^n! Isn't that convenient?

Overflow is also another case of congruency. In our example, if you sum two unsigned numbers 5 and 6, you get 3, which is actually 11.

So, why do you use signed and unsigned? For the CPU there is actually very little difference. For **you** however:

- If the number has n bits, the unsigned represents numbers from 0 to 2^n-1
- If the number has n bits, the signed represents numbers from -2^(n-1) to 2^(n-1)-1

So, for example if you assign -1 to a an unsigned number, it's the same as assigning 2^n-1 to it.

As per your example, that's exactly what you are doing. you are assigning -3 to a uint8_t, which is illegal, but as far as the CPU is concerned you are assigning 253 to it. Then all the rest of the operations are the same for both types and you end up getting the same result.

**There is however a point that your example misses. operator `>>` on signed number extends the sign when shifting. Since the result of both of your operations is 9 before shifting you don't notice this. If you didn't have the +15, you would have -6 in `i` and 250 in `u` which then `>> 2` would result in `-2` in `i` (if printed with %u, 254) and 62 in `u`. (See Peter Cordes' comment below for a few technicalities)**

To understand this better, take this example:

```
  (signed)101011 (-21) >> 3 ----> 111101 (-3)
(unsigned)101011 ( 43) >> 3 ----> 000101 ( 5)
```

If you notice, floor(-21/8) is actually -3 and floor(43/8) is 5. However, -3 and 5 are not equal (and are not congruent modulo 64 (64 because there are 6 bits))

Comment: In C, it's implementation-defined what `>>` does on negative signed integers.  On machines that have arithmetic right-shift operators, that shift in copies of the sign bit, sane compiler-writers use it.  It would be perfectly legal for code to compile `>>` to logical right shift, shifting in zeros.  This allows efficient C implementations on more machines, but the downside is that there's no way to require arithmetic right shift when that is what you need.  This is why it's always recommended to do bit-shifting on unsigned types, to make sure you get the same result on all C implementations.

Comment: Also, C doesn't require 2's complement signed integers, which I think is the more significant reason for leaving signed shifts unsafe.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks, I mentioned your comment in the answer.