# Which datatype is better in calculation of CRC16 for any type of file

Tags: c, embedded, crc

Here i am using two different functions for calculating CRC16 for any type of file `(.txt,.tar,.tar.gz,.bin,.scr,.sh etc)` and different size also varies from `1 KB to 5 GB`.

I want to achieve this

```
   `cross platform 

   less time consuming

   Have to work proper for any type of file and any size`
```

i got same value of CRC in both functions. but any one can tell me which one is more better to calculate CRC16 for any type of file with any size on different different platform.

Here we have to consider 0 to 255 all type characters.

Can any body please suggest me which one is good in my requirements.

Code of both functions :

First one which has `int` datatype in `readChar` here i am using `int readChar`

```
int CRC16_int(const char* filePath) {

    //Declare variable to store CRC result.
    unsigned short result;
    //Declare loop variables.
    int intInnerLoopIndex;
    result = 0xffff; //initialize result variable to perform CRC checksum calculation.

    //Store message which read from file.
    //char content[2000000];

    //Create file pointer to open and read file.
    FILE *readFile;

    //Use to read character from file.
    int readChar;

    //open a file for Reading
    readFile = fopen(filePath, "rb");

    //Checking file is able to open or exists.
    if (!readFile) {
        fputs("Unable to open file %s", stderr);
    }
    /*
     Here reading file and store into variable.
     */
    int chCnt = 0;
    while ((readChar = getc(readFile)) != EOF) {

        //printf("charcater is %c\n",readChar);
        //printf("charcater is %c and int is %d \n",readChar,readChar);
        result ^= (short) (readChar);
        for (intInnerLoopIndex = 0; intInnerLoopIndex < 8; intInnerLoopIndex++) {
            if ((result & 0x0001) == 0x0001) {
                result = result >> 1; //Perform bit shifting.
                result = result ^ 0xa001; //Perform XOR operation on result.
            } else {
                result = result >> 1; //Perform bit shifting.
            }
        }

        //content[chCnt] = readChar;
        chCnt++;
    }
    printf("\nCRC data length in file: %d", chCnt);
    //This is final CRC value for provided message.
    return (result);
}
```

Second one is `unsigned char` datatype of `readChar` Here i am using `unsigned char readChar`

```
int CRC16_unchar(const char* filePath) {

    unsigned int filesize;
    //Declare variable to store CRC result.
    unsigned short result;
    //Declare loop variables.
    unsigned int intOuterLoopIndex, intInnerLoopIndex;
    result = 0xffff; //initialize result variable to perform CRC checksum calculation.
    FILE *readFile;
    //Use to read character from file.
    //The problem is if you read a byte from a file with the hex value (for example) 0xfe, 
    //then the char value will be -2 while the unsigned char value will be 254. 
    //This will significantly affect your CRC 
    unsigned char readChar;
    //open a file for Reading
    readFile = fopen(filePath, "rb");
    //Checking file is able to open or exists.
    if (!readFile) {
        fputs("Unable to open file %s", stderr);
    }
    fseek(readFile, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
    filesize = ftell(readFile); // get current file pointer
    fseek(readFile, 0, SEEK_SET); // seek back to beginning of file
    /*
     Here reading file and store into variable.
     */
    int chCnt = 0;

    for (intOuterLoopIndex = 0; intOuterLoopIndex < filesize; intOuterLoopIndex++) {
        readChar = getc(readFile);
        printf("charcater is %c and int is %d\n",readChar,readChar);

                result ^= (short) (readChar);
                for (intInnerLoopIndex = 0; intInnerLoopIndex < 8; intInnerLoopIndex++) {
                    if ((result & 0x0001) == 0x0001) {
                        result = result >> 1; //Perform bit shifting.
                        result = result ^ 0xa001; //Perform XOR operation on 
                    } else {
                        result = result >> 1; //Perform bit shifting.
                    }
                }
                chCnt++;
    }
    printf("\nCRC data length in file: %d", chCnt);
    return (result);
}
```

Please Help me to figure out this problem

Thanks

Comment: A 16-bit CRC is not very adequate for covering files from 1K to 5GB.  For such large data chunks, there is high probability of CRC matching even with data errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first. Don't do file reading (or whatever the source is) and CRC calculating in the same function. This is bad design. File reading is typically not completely platform independent (although POSIX is your best friend), but CRC calculation can be done very platform independently. Also you might want to reuse your CRC algorithm for other kind of data sources which aren't accessed with `fopen()`.

To give you a hint, the CRC function I always drop in to my projects has this prototype:

```
uint16_t Crc16(const uint8_t* buffer, size_t size, 
                            uint16_t polynomial, uint16_t crc);
```

You don't have to call the function once and feed it the complete contents of the file. Instead you can loop through the file in blocks and call the function for each block. The `polynomial` argument in your case is `0xA001` (which is BTW a polynomial in 'reversed' form), and the `crc` argument is set to `0xFFFF` the first time. Each subsequent time you call the function you pass the previous return value of the function to the `crc` argument.

In your second code frament (`CRC16_unchar`)  you first determine the filesize and then read that number of bytes. Don't do that, it unnecessary limits you to handle files of maximum 4GB (in the most cases). Just reading until EOF is cleaner IMHO.

Furthermore I see that you are struggling with signed/unsigned bytes. Do know that

- `printf` doesn't know if you pass an signed or unsigned integer. You tell `printf` with '%d' or '%u' how to interpret the integer.
- Even in C itself there is hardly a difference between a signed and unsigned integer. C won't magically change the value of 255 to -1 if you do `int8_t x = 255`.

See this anser for more details about when C uses the signedness of an integer: [When does the signedness of an integer really matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040005/when-does-the-signedness-of-an-integer-really-matter/8040207#8040207). Rule of thumb: Just always use `uint8_t` for handling raw bytes.

So both functions are fine regarding signedness/integer size.

EDIT: As other users indicated in their answers, read the file in block instead per-byte:

```
uint16_t CRC16_int(const char* filePath) {
    FILE *readFile;
    const uint8_t buf[1024];
    size_t len;
    uint16_t result = 0xffff;;

    /* Open a file for reading. */
    readFile = fopen(filePath, "rb");
    if (readFile == NULL) {
        exit(1); 
    }

    /* Read until EOF. */
    while ( (len = fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, readFile)) > 0 ) {
        result = Crc16(buf, len, 0xA001, result);
    }

    /* readFile could be in error state, check it with ferror() or feof() functions. */

    return result;
}
```

Also you should alter you function prototype to make it possible to return an error, e.g.:

```
// Return true when successful, false on error. CRC is stored in result.
bool CRC16_int(const char* filePath, uint16_t *result)
```

Comment: Isn't there a problem in the first function in `result ^= (short) (readChar);` because of `readChar` being an `int`? Characters may have values outside of the 0...127 range and result in sign-extension when converted to `int` or `short`.

Comment: @Alex: Indeed, when casting the signedness is considered. I forgot about that (and looked over that line of code too). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I just double checked with the standard, thanks to @user1089679, `getc()/fgetc()` does conversion to `unsigned char` internally, so, it shouldn't be a problem here.

Comment: @Bart I cant understand your this line "Just reading until EOF is cleaner IMHO." EOF is -1 value so in .tar.gz file i getting some problem because 255 converted in to -1 and its EOF so i cant read whole file

Comment: @Bart http://stackoverflow.com/q/9413009/1089679 please refer my this question which creates problem in EOF

Comment: @user1089679: getc() returns an int. The maximum byte value is 0x000000FF and EOF is 0xFFFFFFFF (assuming int is 32 bits on your platform). After determining that the return value of getc() is not EOF it can be safly cast to an uint8_t. There are also other ways to detemine EOF, as the code example at the bottom of my answer shows. That's anyway a more efficient way of reading data (in blocks instead per byte).

Comment: @Bart Thanks For Your Response..Read the file in block is more efficient rather than byte?

Answer (score 1):

You want to read and write 8-bit bytes using `unsigned char` instead of plain `char` because `char` can be either signed or unsigned and that's up to the compiler (allowed by the C standard). So, the value you get from `getc()` should be converted to `unsigned char` prior to being used in the CRC calculations. You could also `fread()` into an `unsigned char`. If you work with signed chars, sign extension of chars into ints will likely break your CRC calculations.

Also, per the C standard `fseek(FilePtr, 0, SEEK_END)` has undefined behavior for binary streams and binary streams need not meaningfully support `SEEK_END` in `fseek()`. In practice, though, this usually works as we want.

Another thing you should consider is checking for I/O errors. Your code is broken in this respect.

Comment: but here fgetc is always return unsinged char so it never gives signed char

Comment: @user1089679: Just double checked with the standard, you're right.

Comment: Can u please tell me which one is better may be i think unsigned char one is better

Comment: I personally prefer to use signed ints only where they are needed even if it means I need to write an extra `unsigned` here or there. At the same time, for greater portability I'd rather rely on `EOF` than on `fseek()`+`ftell()`. So, I'd combine the two.

Comment: :) :) combine of two...good. but May be EOF will be behaving different on other platform ?

Comment: `EOF` must work the same. But you should remember that it will be returned on I/O errors too, not only on end of file. Use `ferror()` to see if `EOF` actually means an I/O error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8168/discussion-between-user1089679-and-alex)

Comment: Mostly i will go for second one function
May be EOF terminate my loop and fseek is working for all other platforms?

Answer (score 0):

The datatype you do the calculation with should, in my opinion, not be the same that you read from the file. Doing one function call into the runtime library to read a single byte is simply not efficient. You should probably read on the order of 2-4 KB at a time, and then iterate over each returned "chunk" in whatever manner you choose.

There's also absolutely no point in reading in the size of the file in advance, you should simply read until reading returns less data than expected, in which case you can inspect `feof()` and `ferror()` to figure out what to do, typically just stop since you're done. See the `fread()` manual page.